# Can a uibutton have an outlet and an action at the same time?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, action, outlet

I have 2 `UIButtons` that change their text label with a switch statement (have only done the 1st case for testing purposes):

```
switch (_itemNumber)
{
    case 0:
        [_phoneButton setTitle:@"201-612-5480" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_emailButton setTitle:@"aacenter@bergen.edu" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.title = @"Acdmc. Adv. Center";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

So when the `UIButton` is pressed an action will be performed:

```
- (IBAction)phoneButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",_emailButton.titleLabel.text]]];
}

- (IBAction)emailButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto://devprograms@apple.com"]];
}
```

Changing the text label works and, but not the action.
Is it because you can only have an outlet or an action for each `UIButton`?
If so how can I manage to perform the desired action?

Answer (score 0):

**The `mailto:` and `tel:` URL schemes do not work on the simulator. Only the device.**

*Previous:*

Have you added any actions to your UIButtons?

```
[_phoneButton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(phoneButtonAction:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_phoneButton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(emailButtonAction:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: - (IBAction)phoneButtonAction:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",_emailButton.titleLabel.text]]];

Comment: - (IBAction)emailButtonAction:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto://devprograms@apple.com"]];

Comment: Are you saying that you have SET UP these actions in Interface builder? I can see that you have actions DEFINED in your code. I am asking if you have programmed your UIButtons to send these actions...

Comment: But you are saying that these actions are not being called?

Comment: They should, because all the connections are there, but when I run the simulator and press the any of the two buttons nothing happens.

Comment: The mailto: and tel: URL schemes do not work on the simulator.

Comment: oh, ok. So you can have an outlet and an action for the same UIButton with no problems, right?

Comment: Yes you can. An outlet is really just an action, but managed by Interface Builder. You can have many actions on the same `UIButton`. If you place a breakpoint or an `NSLog` in either of your two outlets, you will find that they are indeed being called.